# Odoo, write a list in a one2many field

Tags: odoo

I just need to insert into a table the results of a search into a one2many field.

It works, but only write the last record that match the search parameter and I want to write, all of them, not only the last one created.

This is my code.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    domain =[('first_name','=','Luis')]
    student = self.env['university.student'].search(domain)
    for record in student:
        vals.update({'participants_ids':[(0,0,{
        'first_name_participant':record.first_name,
        'last_name_participant':record.last_name,
        })]})
    return super(university_course,self).create(vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get it done like this:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals.update({
        'participants_ids':[
            (0, 0, {
                'first_name_participant': record.first_name,
                'last_name_participant': record.last_name,
            }) for record in self.env['university.student'].search([
                ('first_name','=','Luis')
            ])
        ]
    })
    return super(university_course,self).create(vals)
```